# How to perform multiple table calculation with joins and group by

Tags: sql, time-series, hana

I have two tables client and grouping. They look like this:

**Client**

- C_id
- C_grouping_id
- Month
- Profit

**Grouping**

- Grouping_id
- Month
- Profit

The client table contains monthly profit for every client and every client belongs to a specific grouping scheme specified by C_grouping_id.

The grouping table contains all the groups and their monthly profits.

I'm struggling with a query that essentially calculates the monthly residual for every subscriber:

**Residual= (Subscriber Monthly Profit - Grouping monthly Profit)*(average subscriber monthly profits for all months / average profits for all months for the grouping subscriber belongs to)**

I have come up with the following query so far but the results seem to be incorrect:

```
SELECT client.C_id, client.C_grouping_Id, client.Month,
((client.Profit - grouping.profit) * (avg(client.Profit)/avg(grouping.profit))) as "residual" 
FROM client
INNER JOIN grouping
ON "C_grouping_id"="Grouping_id"
group by client.C_id, client.C_grouping_Id,client.Month, grouping.profit
```

I would appreciate it if someone can shed some light on what I'm doing wrong and how to correct it.

**EDIT**: Adding sample data and desired results

Client

```
C_id     C_grouping_id       Month     Profit

001      aaa                  jul       10$
001      aaa                  aug       12$
001      aaa                  sep       8$
016      abc                  jan       25$
016      abc                  feb       21$
```

Grouping

```
Grouping_id        Month       Profit

 aaa               Jul          30$
 aaa               aug          50$
 aaa               Sep          15$
 abc               Jan          21$
 abc               Feb          27$
```

Query Result:

```
C_ID            C_grouping_id            Month      Residual
001             aaa                      Jul        (10-30)*(10/31.3)=-6.38
```

... and so on for every month for avery client.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: I will add that now. Thank you for the tip.

Comment: Sample data and desired results have been added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done in a pretty straight forward way.
The main difficulty is obviously that you try to deal with different levels of aggregation at once (average of the group and the client as well as the current record).

This is rather difficult/clumsy with simple SELECT FROM GROUP BY-SQL.
But with analytical functions aka [Window functions](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_hanaplatform/helpdata/en/20/a353327519101495dfd0a87060a0d3/content.htm) this is very easy.

Start with combining the tables and calculating the base numbers:

```
select c.c_id as client_id,
           c.c_grouping_id as grouping_id,
           c.month,
           c.profit as client_profit,
           g.profit as group_profit,
           avg (c.profit) over (partition by c.c_id) as avg_client_profit,
           avg (g.profit) over (partition by g.grouping_id) as avg_group_profit
    from client c inner join grouping g
                on c."C_GROUPING_ID"=g."GROUPING_ID"
                and c. "MONTH" = g. "MONTH";
```

With this you already get the average profits by client and by grouping_id.
Be aware that I changed the data type of the currency column to DECIMAL (10,3) as a VARCHAR with a $ sign in it is just hard to convert. 
I also fixed the data for MONTHS as the test data contained different upper/lower case spellings which prevented the join to work.
Finally I turned all column names into upper case to, in order to make typing easier.

Anyhow, running this provides you with the following result set:

```
CLIENT_ID   GROUPING_ID MONTH   CLIENT_PROFIT   GROUP_PROFIT    AVG_CLIENT_PROFIT   AVG_GROUP_PROFIT
16          abc         JAN     25              21              23                  24              
16          abc         FEB     21              27              23                  24              
1           aaa         JUL     10              30              10                  31.666          
1           aaa         AUG     12              50              10                  31.666          
1           aaa         SEP     8               15              10                  31.666
```

From here it's only one step further to the residual calculation.
You can either put this current SQL into a view to make it reusable for other queries or use it as a inline view.

I chose to use it as a common table expression (CTE) aka **WITH clause** because it's nice and easy to read:

```
with p as
    (select c.c_id as client_id,
           c.c_grouping_id as grouping_id,
           c.month,
           c.profit as client_profit,
           g.profit as group_profit,
           avg (c.profit) over (partition by c.c_id) as avg_client_profit,
           avg (g.profit) over (partition by g.grouping_id) as avg_group_profit
    from client c inner join grouping g
                on c."C_GROUPING_ID"=g."GROUPING_ID"
                and c. "MONTH" = g. "MONTH")


select client_id, grouping_id, month, 
       client_profit, group_profit,
       avg_client_profit, avg_group_profit,
       round(    (client_profit - group_profit) 
         *  (avg_client_profit/avg_group_profit), 2) as residual 

from p             
order by grouping_id, month, client_id;
```

Notice how easy to read the whole statement is and how straight forward the residual calculation is done.
The result is then this:

```
CLIENT_ID   GROUPING_ID MONTH   CLIENT_PROFIT   GROUP_PROFIT    AVG_CLIENT_PROFIT   AVG_GROUP_PROFIT    RESIDUAL
1           aaa         AUG     12              50              10                  31.666              -12     
1           aaa         JUL     10              30              10                  31.666              -6.32   
1           aaa         SEP     8               15              10                  31.666              -2.21   
16          abc         FEB     21              27              23                  24                  -5.75   
16          abc         JAN     25              21              23                  24                  3.83
```

Cheers,
Lars

Comment: Thanks for the incredibly detailed answer @LarsB. Your approach is much more readable. However I came up with the following query to solve the problem.

           select c.*,(c.profit-g.profit)*
         ( (select avg(profit) from client c1 where c1.C_id=c.C_id )/
          (select avg(profit) from grouping g1 where                        g1.GroupingId=g.GroupingId )) as residual
          from client c,grouping g
          where c.C_grouping_id=g.GroupingId
          and c.month=g.month